# Unmounting and detaching volumes on AWS ec2 instance not working?

Tags: 16.04, mount, amazon-ec2, aws

Hello good Ubuntu community!

I have an EC2 instance that I'm working with on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS w/ three volumes attached. Device **xvda** is the normal production volume with all current live data, and the other two were used for backup from a while ago. My devices:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

> ```
> NAME                        FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT   LABEL
> xvda                                 250G
> └─xvda1                     ext4     250G /            cloudimg-rootfs
> xvdf                                 250G
> └─xvdf1                     ext4     250G /backup      cloudimg-rootfs
> xvdg                                 250G
> └─xvdg1                     ext4   232.9G /backup/3jun
> loop0                       ext4     100G
> └─docker-202:1-4237516-pool          100G
> loop1                                  2G
> └─docker-202:1-4237516-pool          100G
> ```

I did: `sudo umount dev/xvdf1 && sudo umount dev/xvdg1` then went to my AWS console and detached the volumes.

I ran the command again to see devices info; **xvdg1** and **xvdf1** were gone.

I rebooted the instance and when I try to connect it shows an error message: "connection refused";  I can't ssh into the instance again.

Devices **xvdg1** and **xvdf1** are just backups made over a year ago, I'm getting charged a lot from AWS for having these volumes. I want them gone, any advice?

BTW: I attached them again from the AWS console, now I can ssh into my instance. However, I really want to be able to unmount these and just delete them, since it's just 500 GB of old backups that I don't need.

If anyone can help I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, search in https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ as there's some AWS activity there.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out in case someone else has this problem.

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab

LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0
/dev/xvdf1              /backup ext4    defaults,discard        0 0
/dev/xvdg1              /backup/3jun    ext4 defaults,discard   0 0
```

first line is root volume
dev/xvdf1
dev/xvdg1
are the backup volumes that I'm trying to get rid of you can either remove those two lines or modify to:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0
/dev/xvdf1              /backup ext4    defaults,nofail        0 0
/dev/xvdg1              /backup/3jun    ext4 defaults,nofail   0 0
```

nofail means that if these volumes are not attached when rebooting or starting instance it will still run normally.